# Issue with regular expressions returning an extra empty string

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to use re.findall to get all of the Capitalized words and abbreviations.  I have figured out regular expressions to find each individually, but when I try to combine the two, I end up being returned tuples with an empty string and then the item that I wanted to find.

Here is my regular expression that seems to not work- I imagine its a quick fix I am just unaware of:

```
x = re.findall("([A-Z][A-Za-z]+\.?)|(\\b[A-Z](?:[\\.&]?[A-Z]){2,}\\b)", txt) #just has extra "" in each set
```

edit:

I am currently using this  as my test case:

```
"USA. U.S.A America."
```

This is my output:

```
[('USA.', ''), ('', 'U.S.A'), ('America.', '')]
```

Comment: Could you share a sample value of `txt`?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using "USA. U.S.A America." as my test case.  This is my output:
[('USA.', ''), ('', 'U.S.A'), ('America.', '')]

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Does the abbreviations also start with capital letter? Or could it be `u.s.a`?

Comment: Ideally, just ['USA.', , 'U.S.A', 'America.']. I'm just not sure where the extra empty strings are coming from.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano They can be lowercase, thank you for pointing that out, that wasn't in one of my test cases

Comment: It's a good idea to show your strings as edits in the post body, with monospace font so there's no ambiguity as to the contents of the string.

Comment: Also good to show the expected/desired output (with monospace font) in the question

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression, you have two sets of capturing `(...)`, one for each alternative, so `re.findall()` returns a tuple of them. This is useful if you need to match several parts of a string, or if you need to know which alternative was the one that matched.

In order to get just a flat list, you'll need to either omit those or turn them into non-capturing `(?:...)`:

```
x = re.findall("[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\.?|\\b[A-Z](?:[\\.&]?[A-Z]){2,}\\b", txt)
```

or, if the `(...)` were significant (or you want them for clarity):

```
x = re.findall("(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\.?)|(?:\\b[A-Z](?:[\\.&]?[A-Z]){2,}\\b)", txt)
```

Either of these returns the value: `['USA.', 'U.S.A', 'America.']`

Comment: Thank you!  Now in another test case where the abbreviation has dots throughout (such as "U.S.A."), including the end, the last period is not being captured.  I switched my re to `x = re.findall("(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\.?)|(?:\\b[A-Z](?:[\\.&]?[A-Z]){2,}\.?\\b)", txt)` to try to catch the last period like I have in the first part of the line for normal capitalized words, but it doesnt seem to work the same way.

Comment: Probably a good idea to switch to raw strings, for clarity...

Comment: For debugging regular expressions, try a site like regex101?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(?:...)` to not capture a group as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Here is a simplified version of the combined regex searches of the following:

- Any word that starts with a capital letter
- Any word that is an abbreviation/acronym marked by a separator dot (`.`)

We wouldn't capture those searches individually by putting `(?:...)` per search group. What we would do instead is capture the result of both groups e.g. `( (?:...) | (?:...) )` where the first `(?:...)` is for the capital letter search and the second `(?:...)` is for the acronym search.

```
import re

txt = "USA. U.S.A   America. arctic u.s.a Mars v.. A.b earth c.D.e. .pluto nep.tune. uranus. f.g.h.i Sun  "
matches = re.findall("((?:[A-Z]\w+)|(?:\w+\.+\w+[\w\.]*))", txt)
print(matches)
```

```
['USA', 'U.S.A', 'America', 'u.s.a', 'Mars', 'A.b', 'c.D.e.', 'nep.tune.', 'f.g.h.i', 'Sun']
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I clearly have to review how capture groups work.  I added a part to check to see if the capitalized word ends with a period, but everything else seems good.  Really appreciate the help!

Comment: In my answer, it would omit the ending period for capitalized words. If you don't like that, just change `(?:[A-Z]\w+)` to `(?:[A-Z]\S+)`. In the example, this will change the captured `'USA'` to `'USA.'`.